# Correct Data Member for an Character Array in class

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory

I am implementing the following class in my .hpp file using the OCF (Orthodox canonical form) method:

```
class A {
    public:
        A(const char* theArray, size_t DefualtSize=0);
        ~A();
        A& operator=(const char* anArray);
        
    protected:
        char *theArray;
    };
```

This class will work to take a string and store it in an "A" object on the heap. The implementation in my .cpp file is the following:

```
A::A(const char* anArray, size_t DefaultSize) {
    char *theArray = new char[aDefaultSize];
    strncpy(theArray, anArray, DefaultSize);
};

A::~A() {
    delete[] theArray;
};
```

I was wondering if I correctly added the data member to the class when I wrote "protected: char *theArray;"? Should I have declared the theArray data member as something else/initialized it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually the main problem is your class lacks a copy constructor, which means it's not following OCF (as I understand it).

Comment: Sorry about that, I just added a copy constructor but forgot to add it to my original post. I've also defined my Assignment Operator after posting.

Comment: In modern c++ using [raw-pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) is usually bad practice. Use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) instead of raw-pointers. Use [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) or [deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) instead of pointer array, And [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) or any other [string impl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of char*

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect because you redeclare `theArray`

```
A::A(const char* anArray, size_t DefaultSize) {
    char *theArray = new char[aDefaultSize]; // redeclaration here
    strncpy(theArray, anArray, DefaultSize);
};
```

better is this

```
A::A(const char* anArray, size_t DefaultSize) {
    theArray = new char[aDefaultSize];       // no redeclaration
    strncpy(theArray, anArray, DefaultSize);
};
```

In your version you have declared a local variable `theArray` in your constructor, this variable **hides** the variable declared in the class, so your constructor does not initialise the class variable.

There are other problems, `strncpy` is itself a problematic function since it does not guarantee the resulting array is null terminated.

You have a extra `;` at the end of your constructor definition

Your code will not behave correctly if `new` throws an exception because your destructor will then try to delete an uninitialised pointer. This is better

```
A::A(const char* anArray, size_t DefaultSize) : theArray(nullptr) {
    theArray = new char[aDefaultSize];
    strncpy(theArray, anArray, DefaultSize);
}
```

even better is this

```
A::A(const char* anArray, size_t DefaultSize) : theArray(new char[aDefaultSize]) {
    strncpy(theArray, anArray, DefaultSize);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answers John! I was wondering, after making the change of "char *theArray" to just "theArray" I am getting the error "No matching function for call to 'strncpy'", which is confusing because I didn't change the way the function was being called. Would you happen to have some pointers on how to fix this?

Edit: I realized I change the protected variable in my class to "const char *theArray" and the declaration in the actual function use is "char *(something)" so I changed it back.

Comment: That explains the error, `const char* theArray` in the class is wrong because it says the `theArray` pointer cannot be used to change the data it points at, but that's exactly what you are trying to do when you use `strncpy`.